# Lense-Thirring Precession of short GRBs

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, precession, relativistic-jets

[Stone et al. 2014](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4097) have proposed that the jet resulting from the merger of a black hole (BH) and neutron star (NS) may precess due to [Lense Thirring torques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession)

A large rotating mass e.g. the Earth, can cause the rotation plane of a smaller body, e.g. a satellite, to precess due to gravitomagnetic effects. However I do not understand how this applies to a BH-NS system.

During the merger, an accretion disk around the BH is produced due to the tidal torques from the BH. This accretion onto the BH results in a pair of jets.

My question is then how do Lense-Thirring effects arise here? Is it due to the spin of the BH itself? Through analogy with the earlier example of the Earth and a satellite, which is the Earth and which the satellite for the precessing jets coming out of a BH?